# save id on deffrent table in same time laravel using elequent

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have
**Trans** table
This general table records the relationships of more than 3 tables
There are these fields
Id
*Table* // records the name of the linked table
Row_id
User_id
/////////
And I have a second table called sub_trans
Where fields are
id
Sub_id
Amount
Time
Payment
**Transaction_id**
/////////

Now I have a problem in these two fields
Transaction_id
In the sub_trans table

The second problem is the trans row_id

### I don’t know how to register the id their right, and every necessary table is stored in the database at the same time .

### the relation is subscription HasOne , transaction HasMany , SubscriptionTransaction hasMany

```
 auth()->user()->transactions()->create(['table'  =>'subscription_transactions', // purchase subscription 'row_id' => // this  want to store ]);
```

- 

```
auth()->user()->subscription()->SubscriptionTransaction()->create(['amount' => $card['price'],'date_time' => now()->toDateTimeString(),'type_payment' => $card['paymentBy'],'transaction_id' => // this is want to store ,]);
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni7Sb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrb3S.png)

Comment: add some code please

Comment: added ^_______^